# Why is this not counting correctly?

Tags: c++11, string-length

I am reading text from a text file and need to know the number of characters in the file in total. I thought this should work but it always seems to be overcounting. For example I typed this into my text file:

```
thisisatestthisisa
thisisa
```

And the program returned a total of 32.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    fstream inFile;
    string inputString;

    inFile.open("text.txt", ios::in);

    unsigned int total = 0;
    if (inFile) {
        while (inFile)
        {
            getline(inFile, inputString);

            unsigned int tempStringLength = inputString.length();
            total += tempStringLength;
        }
        cout << "total is: " << total << endl;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "Unable to open file text.txt";
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have return lines? depending on the OS a return line could be 2 chars which could add up if you have a couple. Or maybe a unicode char somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are double-counting the last line in the file.

Because you are using `while(inFile)` instead of `while(getline(inFile, inputString))` the stream's state is not invalidated until the call to `getline(...)`:

Walking through the loop will make this obvious:

Iteration 1:

```
unsigned int total = 0;
//...
    while (inFile) //True
    {
        getline(inFile, inputString); //inFile: True, inputString: thisisatestthisisa

        unsigned int tempStringLength = inputString.length(); //18
        total += tempStringLength; //18
    }
//...
```

Iteration 2:

```
//...
    while (inFile) //True
    {
        getline(inFile, inputString); //inFile: True, inputString: thisisa

        unsigned int tempStringLength = inputString.length(); //7
        total += tempStringLength; //25
    }
//...
```

Iteration 3:

```
//...
    while (inFile) //True
    {
        getline(inFile, inputString); //inFile: EOF, inputString: thisisa (not modified)

        unsigned int tempStringLength = inputString.length(); //7
        total += tempStringLength; //32
    }
//...
```

`inFile` now returns false because the EOF was reached and your loop terminates. Printing 32 as the length.

Long story short: Don't use the file state as a loop terminator. Use the actual read, either `getline` or `operator>>` depending on the situation.